# How to get <a href>'s that appear after a specific <h2>?

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

This is the layout of the webpage:

```
<h2>Featured Ads</h2>
<a href=""></a>

<h2>Ads</h2>
<a href=""></a>
```

There is nothing in the `class` of the regular Ads that I can use to differentiate them. What would be an efficient way to only return the `<a href>`'s that appear after `<h2>Ads</h2>`?

**Update:**

Here's the final code

```
h2 = soup.find("h2", text="Ads")
articles = h2.find_next_siblings("article")

for article in articles:
    for div in article.find_all('div', {'class': 'address'}):
        for link in div.find_all('a', href=True):
            print (link['href'])
```

**Update 2:** had to refactor...

```
articles = soup.find("h2", text="Ads").find_next_siblings("article")
for article in articles:
    ad_url = article.find('a', href=True)['href']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate the `h2` element and [find the next `a` sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
h2 = soup.find("h2", text="Ads")
a = h2.find_next_sibling("a")
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I used `find_next_siblings` so it would find all the url's, should've made that clear in the OP, but I've updated it with my final code.